# xCode crashes on git checkout or stash

Tags: xcode, git

It happens to me regularly (but not always, probably around 50% times) that xCode crashes when using git checkout or stashing the changes (also cherry picking).  After the crash and reopening it crashes again, and again, and after such three-four tries it is finally restored and works properly until I checkout/stash again (all other operations such as committing work fine). Using git from terminal does not help. xCode version is 11.6 (16141).

Part of the crash log:

> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 11E708
> ASSERTION FAILURE in
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-16131.1/DVTUserInterfaceKit/CustomUI/DVTTableCellView.m:178

Comment: No because they say "A crash in -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] usually occurs when you are attempting to insert a nil object into an NSMutableArray.". My crash is not related to the code at all, as I said it happens when I do git checkout / stash changes.

Comment: Does your project or workspace happen to be opened in the Source Control Navigator when the crash occurs? When this happens to me I've found that I had to quickly click on the Project Navigator to break the crash cycle